# Create custom gradle task to build and send apk to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-app-distribution

I want to create a gradle task that will build the apk and send it to firebase. I tried something like this:

```
task sendBuildsForSomething() {
doLast {
    assembleSomething//create APK
    appDistributionUploadSomething//distribute it to firebase
}}
```

But it won't find the property. Am I missing something, is this even possible?
Every piece of documentation is helpin me.
This task in in the projects gradle, and the tasks im trying to call are located in module gradle